# Cannot fetch PDF file as binary data

Tags: java, android, http-headers, httprequest, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to fetch a PDF file from:

URL : https://domain_name/xyz/_id/download/

wherein it doesn't points to a direct pdf file and each unique file gets downloaded
interpreting a particular <_id> field.

I put this link in the address bar of the browser and Pdf file gets downloaded instantly,
while when I try to fetch it by HTTPsURLConnection its Content-Type is in 'text/html' form,
while it should be in 'application/pdf'.

I also tried to 'setRequestProperty' to 'application/pdf' before connecting but file always get downloaded in 'text/html' form.

Method I'm using for it is 'GET'

1) Do I need to use HttpClient instead of HttpsURLConnection?

2) Are these type of links used to increase security?

3) Please point my mistakes out.

4) How can I know the filename present on the server?

I'm pasting below main codes that I've implemented:

```
    URL url = new URL(sb.toString());

    //created new connection
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    //have set the request method and property
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

    Log.e("Content Type--->", urlConnection.getContentType()+"   "+ urlConnection.getResponseCode()+"  "+ urlConnection.getResponseMessage()+"              "+urlConnection.getHeaderField("Content-Type"));

    //and connecting!
    urlConnection.connect();

    //setting the path where we want to save the file
    //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
    //sd card.
    File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    //created a new file, specifying the path, and the filename

    File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"example.pdf");

    if((Environment.getExternalStorageState()).equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY))

    //writing the downloaded data into the file we created
    FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

    //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    //this is the total size of the file
    int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

    //variable to store total downloaded bytes
    Log.e("Total File Size ---->", ""+totalSize);
    int downloadedSize = 0;

    //create a buffer...
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

    //Reading through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
    while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {

        //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
        fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);


        //adding up the size
        downloadedSize += bufferLength;

        //reporting the progress:
        Log.e("This much downloaded---->",""+ downloadedSize);

    }
    //closed the output stream
    fileOutput.close();
```

I have searched a lot and couldn't get the result.
If possible please try to elaborate my mistake as I'm implementing this 
thing for the first time.

**Tried fetching direct pdf links like: http://labs.google.com/papers/bigtable-osdi06.pdf
  and they get downloaded easily, moreover their 'Content-Type' was also 'application/pdf' **

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the MIME type the server is responding with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread led me to the solution for my problem!
When you try to download a streamed PDF from the WebView and you use a HttpURLConnection you need to also pass the cookies from within the Webview.

```
String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url.toString());
if (cookie != null) connection.setRequestProperty("cookie", cookie);
```

Answer (score 1):

Theory 1 :  The server is responding with incorrect Content type in response. If server code is written and deployed by you check that.

Theory 2 : The url is returning an html page which has some javascript in it which redirects page to the url of the actual pdf file.

Comment: The URL I'm trying to open has some inline pdf rendering wherein it shows pdf files embedded in webpage. Do, you think this can be an issue? Cause, when I use Firefox browser it renders it within WebPage but when I open this link in Chrome Browser it downloads the file. So, is there anything I can do to directly fetch pdf as binary rather than receiving 'html/ text' or the amendments are needed to be made on server side. I haven't deployed the server code.

Comment: @al-sutton @nishan I have checked through FireBug it shows it as application/pdf object. So, do I need to do some change to access embedded pdf in a webpage.

Comment: Also, I'm able to download the exact file size of the pdf but in 'text/ html', rather than receiving it as 'application/ pdf' so, it shows "Couldn't open text/html file type"

Comment: Hi, the problem was I wasn't sending cookies along so there was authentication failure, wherein it was downloading html page. I'm setting the Nishan's answer as accepted one as it allowed me to see all the possible mistakes I could have done and finally got to know where I was wrong. Thanks for replying guys.