# Webview download PDF to phone

Tags: android, file, pdf, webview, download

Currently i'm trying to display some "dynamic" PDF files in my Webview.
These PDF's are loaded from a database and "streamed" the the browser, this works fine in all the PC browsers and even in the Android browser. 
I tried "content-type: application/pdf" and even "application/octet-stream", but both give the same result.

I tried downloading the PDF with HttpClient and HttpURLConnection but everything I try the getContentLength(); and getInputStream(); keep saying its only 100B.

So when I startup a PDF intent Android tells me that its not a correct PDF file.

Only when I use a downloadListener and put the URL into a intent (without downloading first) the Webview opens the default browser wich automaticly starts download right away.

So the way I present a PDF seems to work. But the way I try to get the stream from the URL does not.

Loads of questions about this topic, sadly very little correct/working answers...

Kinds Regards!

EDIT: The URL is not www.xxx.com/file.pdf, but it's www.xxx.com/file.php?id=12345
So when I open the URL in the Mobile Browser the browser starts downloading it, but the download code in my Webview just can seem to see/find a file.

Comment: Seems I have exactly the same problem as here this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256149/cannot-fetch-pdf-file-as-binary-data

Answer (score 3):

I finnaly found the solution!
I needed so pass through the authentication cookies from the WebView!

So adding the following code fixed my problem;

```
String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url.toString());
if (cookie != null) connection.setRequestProperty("cookie", cookie);
```